# Why is the background color red? (how to decide which css rule will win)

Tags: css

I am just playing with css to learn. I am unable to understand why I am getting red as the background color while I expect it to be green or yellow.

### CSS

```
div
{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
body > div
{
    background-color:red;
}

div
{
    background-color:yellow;
}
*{
    background-color:green;
}
```

### Html

```
<div>
    red
</div>
```

Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/XxDcL/

**I am looking for the reason, why its happening so**, not fixes to make the div's background color to yellow or green.

Comment: The `body > div` is more specific than the `div` i guess

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

Answer (score 1):

The `body > div` is more specific than the `div` may be you have to write like this:

```
body > div
{
    background-color:red;
}

body div
{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

or give a `class` to that `div`

```
.yellow{
        background-color:yellow;
    }
```

That rule win which is more specify 
for example:

```
div{
        background-color:yellow;
    }
```

define `class` is more powerful then only `div`

```
.red
{
    background-color:red;
}

div.red
    {
        background-color:pink;/*more specify than only class red*/
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

one word **"specificity"** , its very important in css, there is a wonderful resource here to learn ,

[image: Specificity order]

http://css-tricks.com/855-specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to override the red div background with the green, In that case you need to override this red divwith `!important` css property.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/XxDcL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The '>' signifies any children of the first tag e.g. 'body > div' would mean all the styles from 'body' would be passed onto the 'div'.

http://jsfiddle.net/djsbaker/XxDcL/2/

Have a play around without the '>' and with naming your divs (see above jsfiddle). Naming your divs will give your more control.